# Enable Knowledge and milestone in cases service console

Tags: page-layout, service-cloud-console

I am using a service console in the development org. When I create a new case, knowledge and milestone is not displayed in the right side of the screen. I have already checked the checkbox in the layout properties of the case layout. How can I make them appear? Is that feature not available for the development org? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check user detail page > check the knowledge user checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

First check that if you configure console correctly. Take help from [Service Console Configuration.](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/service_basics/service_basics_configure_console)

Then check if you have enabled the Knowledge user checkbox. It will solve your problem.[image]

Comment: yes, I have already checked it yet nothing happens